# Javascript random right answer

Tags: javascript, random

[image]

I would like to generate wrong number randomly between other slots.

Eg: the right answer is 4, but I want to make other slots give the wrong answer between the right answer.

Can anyone gives me a clue to achieve this? Thanks you in advance!

Sorry for my bad English, If you don't get my question.

```
    var operators = {
        "signOne": [
            {
                sign: "+",
                method: function(a,b) {return a+b}
            },
            {
                sign: "-",
                method: function(a,b) { return a-b}
            }
        ]};
var selectedOperatorA = Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.signOne.length);
this.hiddenTotalValue = operators.signOne[selectedOperatorA].method(this.valueA, this.valueB);
```

here is the output of my right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Build a list containing the right answer, a smaller wrong answer and a bigger wrong answer
- Sort the list with a custom random function

Code:

```
var answer = 9 - 5,
    list = [
      answer,
      answer - 1 - ((Math.random() * 10) | 0),
      answer + 1 + ((Math.random() * 10) | 0)
    ];

list.sort(function(a, b) { return Math.random() - 0.5; });

console.log(list);
```

Example output:

```
[2, 8, 4]
```

If needed, the position of the correct answer in the list would be given by `list.indexOf(answer);`.

Comment: That would result in a quiz that you can win by selecting the middle value. The player wouldn't need to solve the math tasks to find the answer as soon as he noticed the pattern.

Comment: @MalteKöhrer I fully agree, but I think that's what the OP is asking for. Actually, he didn't specify if the positions of the answers should be shuffled at all. This is my own assumption.

Comment: Thanks you for answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the real answer `calcAnswer()` and then create a function to create random numbers that is `calcOtherAnswers()` less than the real answer where as long as the `result` < `answer` (4 or whatever in your case) then generate a number.

Comment: you create a pattern this way. the right answer is always the max of the answers

Answer (score 0):

Try using Math.random(); function to generate random numbers.

**HTML**

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var first = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var second = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
while( second === first ){
  second = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
var third = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
while( third === first || third === second ){
  third = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

$("#first").html(first);
$("#second").html(second);
$("#third").html(third);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you posted the question for javascript, and I am posting an answer assuming that language. 
From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) at Mozilla you can choose your max and min using a function.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

put in the proper values of min and max

Answer (score 0):

```
var operators = {
        "signOne": [
            {
                sign: "+",
                method: function(a,b) {return a+b}
            },
            {
                sign: "-",
                method: function(a,b) { return a-b}
            }
        ]};
var selectedOperatorA = Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.signOne.length);
this.hiddenTotalValue = operators.signOne[selectedOperatorA].method(this.valueA, this.valueB);
```

here is the output of my right answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be having an array. You push the correct value into it, then have a loop that creates random numbers and adds them if they are not inside the array yet - until the array has the required size/length.